# Is "al" a relatively new word?

Tags: etimología, historia, contracciones

I am curious about the history of the word "al".  For example, was there a time when "a el" was the proper usage and "al" came later (presumably because of the slurring of speech)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this page](http://www.elcastellano.org/consultas.php?Op=ver&Id=25855) (emphasis mine):

> Las contracciones **al** y **del** aparecen en la lengua escrita siglos antes de que existiera la Real Academia, como lo atestiguan numerosos documentos de entre los **siglos X y 
>   XVIII**.
>
> (...)
>
> Los académicos no hicieron sino recoger este uso, de manera que en la primera edición del Diccionario de Autoridades, en 1726, aparece consignada **al** y en su segunda edición, en 1732, del, registrándose ambas en todas las ediciones sucesivas del Diccionario académico, hasta nuestros días.