# ¿Han existido excepciones a la norma de "a + el = al" aparte de las actuales?

Tags: ortografía, preposiciones, historia, contracciones

Hoy en día sabemos que, salvo excepciones, debemos escribir *al* en lugar de *a el*. Sin embargo, esto parece que no siempre fue así:

[image: á el]

La imagen corresponde a la definición de "niño" según el diccionario de la RAE de 1783, que duró hasta la edición de 1803 inclusive. Se puede ver como se usa "á el" en un contexto que hoy en día no corresponde con ninguna excepción, ya que diríamos "se aplica al que no ha llegado". De hecho, en la misma definición más adelante dice "se extiende [...] al que tiene pocos años", usando (ahí sí) la contracción.

Por tanto, ¿a qué excepción corresponde el que en esta definición se usara "á el" separado? ¿Qué diferencia hay entre dicho "á el" y el "al" posterior? ¿Cómo evolucionó esta norma hasta llegar a la actual?

Como añadido, hacer notar que la [primera gramática](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Gramatica_RAE_1771_reducida.pdf) (PDF) de la RAE, de 1771, dice lo siguiente en la parte I, capítulo V, correspondiente a los artículos:

> El artículo singular masculino pierde la primera letra siempre que le precede inmediatamente la preposicion *a*, ó la preposicion *de* para evitar la concurrencia de dos vocales; y formando una sola voz de la preposicion y el artículo decimos: servir *al* Rey: cumplir las órdenes *del* Rey: cuyo uso es mas acertado que el de algunos que por afectacion dicen: *de el*, y *á el*. Esta exactitud conviene quando esta palabra *el* es pronombre, y no artículo, como: Fulano sintió que hablasen mal *de él* [...].

No añade ninguna excepción. Dado el caso, ¿podría tratarse de un error gramatical en el propio diccionario? ¿O la regla por aquel entonces era más bien una recomendación?

Por si sirve de pista, en el CORDE se pueden encontrar las siguientes ocurrencias de "á el":

```
1000-1500    136 casos en  38 documentos
1500-1600    178 casos en  73 documentos
1600-1700    924 casos en  51 documentos
1700-1800    671 casos en 103 documentos
1800-1900    149 casos en  61 documentos
1900-2000     39 casos en  15 documentos (el último hacia 1910)
```

Algunos de los casos encontrados usan "el" como "él" (pronombre), pero son una minoría. Es decir, que parece ser que esta falta de contracción era algo que se daba con bastante frecuencia, y que no paró por completo hasta que la preposición "á" perdió su tilde.

Comment: Is the accent on the _a_ important? Both of them seem to have it.

Comment: @mdewey I don't think so, as in that age the _a_ preposition always had the accent.

Comment: Sin pensar en lo de arriba demasiado, ¿qué te suena mejor?  ¿*que se aplica a la que no ha llegado* o *que se aplica a ella que no ha llegado*?  ¿*de hablar a ella que tiene* o *de hablar a la que tiene*?

Comment: @guifa pues las formas que usan "la" me suenan mejor que las que usan "ella".

Comment: Pregunté por si, quizás, el que escribió la definición quiso decir *él* en vez de *el*, pero no será así si la preferencia sería por *la*. El portugués tiene más circunstancias en las que no se permite la contracción, pero no se aplicarían a (ja) estos ejemplos (sería: *que se aplica ao que não chegou* e *(que) se extende … ao que tem*). La única idea que se me viene a le mente es que, debido a las vocales precedentes, la pronunciación con contracción saldría más bien como *siaplícal que…*, pero por separado, sale como *siaplica el que*, pero deben poder entenderse igual de bien.

Comment: @guifa me resultaría rara una redacción en plan "a él que no ha llegado" dado que así implicaría que sabes quién es "él", cosa imposible en una definición. Por otro lado, también me resulta curioso que al final de la definición y en un caso idéntico sí lo contrajeran ("se extiende al que tiene"). También me resulta improbable (aunque no imposible) el que se dejara "á el" para evitar una cacofonía (¿sería porque la palabra anterior acaba en -a?).

Comment: Quizá [este paper](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/1976627.pdf) pueda servir para un panorama más amplio, aunque no responda la pregunta específicamente. Es un análisis de 23 gramáticas españolas de diferentes autores y épocas en lo que respecta a las contracciones gramaticales. En principio parece que las contracciones aceptadas han ido disminuyendo mientras que la estandarización de su escritura ha ido aumentando.

Comment: relacionado: [Is “al” a relatively new word?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/381/is-al-a-relatively-new-word)

Answer (score 2):

*Lo siguiente es una conjetura, como casi todo lo relacionado con las normas gramaticales pre-RAE.*

---

En 1559, en su [*Gramática de la lengua vulgar de España*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/obref/fortuna/expo/lengua/lengu0112.htm), Bartolomé Gravio escribía lo siguiente ([fuente](https://books.google.es/books?id=5cxMAAAAcAAJ&dq=gramatica%20espa%C3%B1ola&hl=es&pg=PP35#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

[image]

> *En el segundo y tercer caso no decimos "de el", ni "a el", como veis; por causa, que no está puesto en uso, porque (como yo pienso) sonaría muy mal; y así decimos "del", "al".*

Aquí noto varias cosas:

- que diferencia las formas en base a los casos latinos: "el" para nominativo y acusativo, "del" para genitivo y ablativo, y "al" para dativo;
- que usa las mismas formas para el plural: "delós", "alós"; y también para el femenino y el neutro: "delá", "alá", "delas", "alas", "delo", "alo" (no salen en la imagen, pero se pueden ver en la fuente);
- que todas las formas las escribe juntas, como una sola palabra.

Este último aspecto, escribir "delós", "alo" y demás, lo he encontrado en otros libros de la época. Es como si para estos autores, "del", "delos", etc. no fuesen contracciones, sino palabras de pleno derecho: simplemente, el artículo en nominativo es "el", "la", "lo" y en genitivo es "del", "dela", "delo", como si los artículos tuviesen declinaciones.

Antes que Gravio, decía también Nebrija en el [capítulo VII del libro segundo](http://bdh-rd.bne.es/viewer.vm?id=0000174208&page=27) de su *Gramática castellana* (transcripción modernizada):

> *Acontece muchas veces, que cuando alguna palabra acaba en vocal y si le sigue otra que comienza lo mismo en vocal, echamos fuera la primera de ellas (...) A esta figura los griegos llaman sinalefa. Los latinos compression. Nosotros la podemos llamar ahogamiento de vocales. **Los griegos ni escriben ni pronuncian la vocal que echan fuera, así en verso como en prosa**. **Nuestra lengua**
>    (...) **así en verso como en prosa, a veces escribe y pronuncia esa vocal, aunque le siga otra vocal**
>    (...) **[y] a veces ni escribimos ni pronunciamos esa vocal** (...) Y esto no solamente en la necesidad del verso, mas aun en la oración suelta. Como si escribieses "nuestro amigo esta aqui", lo puedes pronunciar como se escribe, y por esta figura lo puedes pronunciar [también] "nuestramigo staqui". **Los latinos en prosa siempre escriben y pronuncian la vocal al final de la dicción, aunque después le siga otra vocal. En verso la escriben y no la pronuncian**.*

Ya sabemos que antes de la RAE había dos corrientes gramaticales diferenciadas: la de quienes abogaban por escribir como se pronuncia (el propio Nebrija, Correas, etc.) y la de quienes pretendían que la gramática se basase en la escritura más que en el habla (fray Miguel de Salinas entre otros).

Es posible que aparte hubiese también otra división, entre aquellos que preferían escribir como los griegos, y por tanto escribirían y pronunciarían siempre "del", y aquellos que se basaban más en el latín, escribiendo "de el" y pronunciando "de el" o "del" según se quisiese diferenciar la prosa del verso.

Uniendo los grupos, lo más probable es que la mayoría de la gente pronunciase "del" siempre, dándose las diferencias únicamente en la escritura según la escuela de la que viniese cada cual. Y siendo que al final tuvo mayor aceptación la corriente de adaptar la gramática a la pronunciación más que a la escritura, lo normal sería escribir "al" y "del" y, tal como explicaba la RAE, quienes marcaban la separación "a el" y "de el" lo hacían simplemente por afectación y por dárselas de cultos y latinos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, nos has descubierto algunas gramáticas antiguas bastante interesantes. No parece una mala conjetura, pero me queda la duda: una definición del diccionario debería estar hecha por una única persona (es una unidad lo suficientemente pequeña), y si es así, ¿por qué en la misma definición se puede encontrar "a el" y "al"?

Comment: También se me ocurre que, aplicando el concepto de sinalefa mencionado en tu respuesta, se pueda considerar que en el primer caso "aplica á" es una sinalefa, que haría que la "á" no se pronunciara y por tanto "el" quedaría libre. En el segundo caso "hablar al" no produciría sinalefa.

Comment: me parece que aqui el problema es de redaccion mas que de gramatica. 

parece que se quiso acentuar la "á" para hacer una pausa entre el antes y el despues, a mi parecer esto deberia haberse utilizado una coma o los dos puntos.

Comment: @Mike por aquel entonces (y hasta principios del siglo XX) la preposición _á_ se tildaba siempre. No era cuestión de que se tildara para dar énfasis o marcar pausas, era que siempre la llevaba.